# How do Twitter clients on a phone get notified of changes?

Tags: twitter

I am playing with the Twitter API. When I unlike something using the API, the tweet disappears almost immediately in Tweetbot on my phone. How does the mobile app know about the change? Since the API is rate-limited quite aggressively, I guess it can’t be polling. Is there some kind of notification API for events? Or is this implemented using the [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the streaming API. There’s an [event stream](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/messages-types#Events_event) that contains messages for likes and unlikes.